# How can I import perl scripts in a project using Epic?

Tags: eclipse, perl, eclipse-plugin, epic

I am interested in using `Epic` for `Perl` development as my background is `Java`. So I have installed Epic in my Eclipse.
There is already a source code repository with perl scripts in a remote file system.
My question is, if I mount the remote file system how am I supposed to use `Eclipse` to work on the scripts?
In `Java` there files would be under a project (with the corresponding files).
I see that there is an equivalent `Eclipse Project` in the Eclipse menu after installing `Epic`.
So how would I access the perl scripts? Some how add them under a new project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First map your network drive/mount your remote file system.

Go to File -> New -> Perl Project (or project and then select Perl from the list), name it, click Finish.

Right click on the project in your Navigator Tab and click Import...

Under General select File System, click next.

Click browse and select your file system, this will be the one on your remote machine.

Check the files you want to import.

Expand the Advanced Tab and check "Create links in workspace." (This part is the trick to edit the files on your remote machine instead of copying them locally and having two locations)

Click Finish.

Please comment if you have any questions, I set this up a while ago and I believe that's what I did but it's not currently working on my machine.

Comment: `Check the files you want to import.` I will select individual perl scripts or directories?I have a file structure that composes a "project". But not an eclipse project

Comment: You can check the whole directory, or specific files. There are little check boxes.

Comment: This seems to work for me.I have other issues that are related to having a matching setup of the repos with my eclipse but I will open a new question for this.I add the link as a comment so you can also review it.

Comment: You can checkout:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760498/how-can-i-make-eclipse-perl-project-use-a-specific-perl-version