# How can I make eclipse perl project use a specific perl version?

Tags: eclipse, perl, eclipse-plugin, epic

I have mounts of a remote source code repos in `Linux` servers.
I use Eclipse `Epic` and I have made links to the scripts there with the help of the answer of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684903/how-can-i-import-perl-scripts-in-a-project-using-epic/17685686#comment25769660_17685686).
My problem is the following:
The project in the remote repository uses a specific version of `Perl` which is under a specific directory.
How would I configure my project in `Eclipse` to have/use exactly the same `Perl`?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this with an interpreter on a remote machine and I'm on Windows but I think this would work.

1. Go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Perl EPIC`
2. Click `...` next to `Perl executable` and choose the location you want (this would be under your remote repository)
3. Click `Apply` / `OK`

To check if it works, just do this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Version: $]\n";
print "Interpreter: $^X\n";
```

Comment: Can also do $^V to get version string

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, because I have some Perl32 and Perl64 programs which I have to compile with different interpreters.
And think, the main question was:
"How can I use a particular perl interpreter for each project?"

EPICs preferences will change the interpreter for all projects, but not for a single one.

My solution was to create a small script as a wrapper for the perl interpreter.
Then, in the properties of each project, I added a meaningless Perl Include Path, which serves only as a hint on the interpreter, because EPIC passes this Include Path as a parameter to perl.
The wrapper script then looks for this hint and fires the right perl version.